Make only selected vertices collide?
How can I make cloth physics only affect the selected part?
Thanks in advance.


I was able to fix this by inverting the selected part with Ctrl+i and adding it to a new vertex group. Then I selected this new vertex group in the Clothing Simulator > Shape > Pin Group options and it worked.
